# error when running flutter default project

Tags: flutter

this error appears when running any flutter project on windows 11 machine using androidstudio or vscode

Launching lib\main.dart on M2101K9AG in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2@2d5bf9c0.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4a80aa73e8a13b852cc298900b6ce78c.bin' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin).
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache$2.run(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:74)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:449)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.put(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:71)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2.run(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$2.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:180)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:220)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:201)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.flushOperations(CacheAccessWorker.java:175)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 100833 found in cache 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.blockCorruptedException(FileBackedBlockStore.java:267)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:246)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CachingBlockStore.read(CachingBlockStore.java:100)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore.read(FreeListBlockStore.java:86)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.read(StateCheckBlockStore.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:147)
... 19 more
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2@713b68b.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4cb87de3b8f0e7a6d84d92c8d342f34a.bin' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin).
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache$2.run(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:74)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:449)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.put(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:71)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2.run(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$2.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:185)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:220)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:201)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.flushOperations(CacheAccessWorker.java:175)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 100858 found in cache 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.blockCorruptedException(FileBackedBlockStore.java:267)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:246)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CachingBlockStore.read(CachingBlockStore.java:100)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore.read(FreeListBlockStore.java:86)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.read(StateCheckBlockStore.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:147)
org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:449)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.read(StateCheckBlockStore.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:147)
... 19 more
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2@5ce0168e.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\40be8819594f13c5f88eda1c223a9b3d.bin' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin).
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache$2.run(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:74)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:449)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.put(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:71)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2.run(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$2.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:185)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:220)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:201)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.flushOperations(CacheAccessWorker.java:175)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 104833 found in cache 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.blockCorruptedException(FileBackedBlockStore.java:267)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:246)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CachingBlockStore.read(CachingBlockStore.java:100)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore.read(FreeListBlockStore.java:86)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.read(StateCheckBlockStore.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:147)
... 19 more
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2@16c9acd8.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\40be8819594f13c5f88eda1c223a9b3d' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin).
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache$2.run(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:74)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:449)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.put(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:71)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2.run(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$2.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:185)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:220)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:201)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.flushOperations(CacheAccessWorker.java:175)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 104858 found in cache 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.blockCorruptedException(FileBackedBlockStore.java:267)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:246)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CachingBlockStore.read(CachingBlockStore.java:100)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore.read(FreeListBlockStore.java:86)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.read(StateCheckBlockStore.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:147)
... 19 more
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2@6b9235d7.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\eb73a997f65dfd5d9e90c30f95a2ff6f.bin' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin).
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache$2.run(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:74)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:449)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.put(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:71)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2.run(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$2.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:185)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:220)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:201)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.flushOperations(CacheAccessWorker.java:175)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 104258 found in cache 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.blockCorruptedException(FileBackedBlockStore.java:267)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:246)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CachingBlockStore.read(CachingBlockStore.java:100)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore.read(FreeListBlockStore.java:86)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.read(StateCheckBlockStore.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:147)
... 19 more
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2@66f4bec2.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\eb73a997f65dfd5d9e90c30f95a2ff6f' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin).
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache$2.run(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:74)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:449)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.put(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:71)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2.run(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$2.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:185)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:220)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:201)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.flushOperations(CacheAccessWorker.java:175)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 104308 found in cache 'C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.blockCorruptedException(FileBackedBlockStore.java:267)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:246)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CachingBlockStore.read(CachingBlockStore.java:100)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore.read(FreeListBlockStore.java:86)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.read(StateCheckBlockStore.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:147)
... 19 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform window-java-1.0.0-beta04.aar (androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ad201fac15a88598107ec645f351f5b4\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04.
> > Cannot parse result path string:

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 22s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link, it may be the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59509560/execution-failed-for-task-appdesugardebugfiledependencies)
or you can check two build.gradle in the Android folder in flutter project and change the kotlin version, compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.

Comment: i made this changes and i got the same result on this device but the same project works on another windows 11 device with out any modifications